# Simplifying expression and arranging terms in power of exponent

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have lots of expressions like below which I want to simplify but I am not sure how to do it in Mathematica. I am looking to simplify them in the form of $\Sigma _i A_i e^{y_i}$ where $A_i$ will be the simplest fraction corresponding to different values of exponential powers $y_i$. Can someone help and also point me to resources for Mathematica programming so that I can learn?

My expression:
$$
\frac{\lambda _1^3 e^{-\Gamma  \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1+\lambda _r\right)} \left(\lambda _r e^{\Gamma  \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1\right)} \left(e^{\Gamma  \lambda _r}-1\right)-\lambda _2 \mu  \left(e^{\Gamma  \lambda _2 \mu } \left(e^{\Gamma  \lambda _1}+e^{\Gamma  \lambda _r}-e^{\Gamma  \left(\lambda _1+\lambda _r\right)}\right)-1\right)\right)}{\left(-\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1-\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1-\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1+\lambda _r\right)} + \frac{\lambda _1^2 e^{-\Gamma  \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1+\lambda _r\right)} \left(e^{\Gamma  \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _r\right)} \left(\lambda _2^2 \mu ^2 \left(e^{\Gamma  \lambda _1}-1\right)-\left(e^{\Gamma  \lambda _1}-1\right) \lambda _r^2+2 \lambda _2 \mu  \lambda _r\right)-2 \lambda _2 \mu  \lambda _r\right)}{\left(-\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1-\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1-\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _r\right) \left(\lambda _2 \mu +\lambda _1+\lambda _r\right)}
    $$
with assumptions:
$$
\mu >0,\mu \in \mathbb{R},\mu <1,\Gamma >0,\Gamma \in \mathbb{R},\lambda _1>0,\lambda _1\in \mathbb{R},\lambda _2>0,\lambda _2\in \mathbb{R},\lambda _r>0,\lambda _r\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Following is the input form

```
(Subscript[λ, 1]^3*
            (-((-1 + E^(Γ*μ*Subscript[λ, 2])*
                         (E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]) + 
                 E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, r]) - 
                            E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
                    Subscript[λ, r]))))*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]) + 
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2]))*
                 (-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, r]))*
          Subscript[λ, r]))/
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
                 Subscript[λ, r]))/
       ((Subscript[λ, 1] - μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - 
             Subscript[λ, r])*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
             μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, r])*
          (μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r])*
          (Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
             Subscript[λ, r])) + 
     (Subscript[λ, 1]^2*(-2*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]*
                 Subscript[λ, r] + 
               E^(Γ*(μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
                         Subscript[λ, r]))*
                 ((-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]))*μ^2*
             Subscript[λ, 2]^2 + 2*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]*
             Subscript[λ, r] - 
                    (-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]))*
             Subscript[λ, r]^2)))/
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*
           Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r]))/
       ((Subscript[λ, 1] - μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - 
             Subscript[λ, r])*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
             μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, r])*
          (μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r])*
          (Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
             Subscript[λ, r]));

assume = {0 < μ < 
    1, {Γ, Subscript[λ, 1], Subscript[λ, 2], 
     Subscript[λ, r]} ∈ PositiveReals};
```

Comment: What do you know about the variables? Are any real or positive or negative or constrained to an interval or .… To get the simplest form you must tell Mathematica all that you know.

Comment: Assuming that there are some constraints on the variables, when you edit your question to include the constraints, also include the Mathematica code (InputForm) for your expression so that it can be copy and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: @BobHanlon Updated the question as per your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) of an expression does not display any of the box structure. The `InputForm` of your expression is

```
expr = (Subscript[λ, 1]^3*
            (-((-1 + E^(Γ*μ*Subscript[λ, 2])*
                         (E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]) + 
                 E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, r]) - 
                            E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
                    Subscript[λ, r]))))*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]) + 
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2]))*
                 (-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, r]))*
          Subscript[λ, r]))/
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
                 Subscript[λ, r]))/
       ((Subscript[λ, 1] - μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - 
             Subscript[λ, r])*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
             μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, r])*
          (μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r])*
          (Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
             Subscript[λ, r])) + 
     (Subscript[λ, 1]^2*(-2*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]*
                 Subscript[λ, r] + 
               E^(Γ*(μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
                         Subscript[λ, r]))*
                 ((-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]))*μ^2*
             Subscript[λ, 2]^2 + 2*μ*Subscript[λ, 2]*
             Subscript[λ, r] - 
                    (-1 + E^(Γ*Subscript[λ, 1]))*
             Subscript[λ, r]^2)))/
         E^(Γ*(Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*
           Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r]))/
       ((Subscript[λ, 1] - μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - 
             Subscript[λ, r])*(Subscript[λ, 1] + 
             μ*Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, r])*
          (μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, r])*
          (Subscript[λ, 1] + μ*Subscript[λ, 2] + 
             Subscript[λ, r]));

assume = {0 < μ < 
    1, {Γ, Subscript[λ, 1], Subscript[λ, 2], 
     Subscript[λ, r]} ∈ PositiveReals};

LeafCount /@ {expr, Simplify[expr], Simplify[expr, assume], 
  FullSimplify[expr], FullSimplify[expr, assume]}

(* {303, 249, 249, 242, 242} *)
```

So, in this case, the assumptions don't help in the simplification

```
expr2 = expr // FullSimplify
```

[image]

**EDIT 4:** Amended to handle terms without exponential

```
{coef, exp} = 
  Transpose[(If[FreeQ[#, Power[E, _]], {#, 0}, #] & /@ 
    (List @@ Expand[expr2])) /. 
       a_*Exp[b_] :> {a, Simplify[b]}];
```

**EDIT 3:** To combine terms with like exponents

```
{coef, exp} = 
  Transpose[
   Transpose[{coef, exp}] //. {start___, {c1_, e1_}, mid___, {c2_, e1_}, 
      end___} :> {start, {Simplify[c1 + c2], e1}, mid, end}];

expr2 == (coef . Exp[exp]) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean...what do you mean by "does not display any of the box structure"...do you mean to say that it cannot be simplified any further? 
Is there anyway to arrange the expression such that it expands it in different power of exponential.... meaning something of the form A.e^y where A is simplified factor corresponding to  e^y and y will be taking different values in above expression.

Comment: The code that you posted contains `SubsuperscriptBox`, i.e., box structure. Note that this is not in the expression that I pasted. Perhaps you want `expr3 = expr2 // Expand`; however, this is somewhat the opposite of simplification.

Comment: Got it. Thanks regarding box structure. 
What I am looking for is expressing this large expression (I have atleast 5 more such terms in the expression I am trying to simplify) to be simplified and arranged in form of \sum Ai * e^yi where Ai will be different for different yi ..... since yi will be different, it cannot be simplified any further, but the corresponding Ai will be the most simplified fraction for that particular yi.

Is there anyway I can do that in mathematica?.... of course using pen and paper is last resort.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect what you are actually trying to accomplish. People cannot guess that from what you posted.

Comment: I have edited the question and updated the input form as per your answer. Hopefully its clear now what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Suggestion: Is this possible using Collect[ExpandAll[expr,????]] where ??? is a suitable wildcard pattern? BTW. I am no expert on pattern matching

Comment: @OpticsMan I have no idea about it either. I am pretty new in using mathematica.

Comment: @BobHanlon I tried your edit and I am getting True, any explanation as to what its trying to do?

Comment: It is producing the sum that you requested from the list of coefficients and the list of exponents. The sum is just the `Dot` product

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. I dont quite understand all the operations. Can you please point to some programming book reference or something which I can use to understand what all operations are happening.

Secondly I looked the values of exp, and herein lies the issue. These exponents can be simplified and then possibly the coefs associated with them also. For example, the list of exp, the 4th and 6th (counting from 1) are actually evaluating to 0 and hence the 2 coefficients corresponding to those exponents can be combined. Thats a problem and I dont know how to solve that. Any suggestion?

Comment: The online documentation is readily available. For any unknown function or operator, highlight it with the mouse and press `F1` for help. See also, [`An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/) and the links there.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks a lot for your kind updated answer and help. The updated result shows only 4 simplified exponents and corresponding simplified coefficient as opposed to initial 12. This seems to solve the issue. I dont know why FullSimplify cannot do similar.  Will start looking into the reference you pointed to. Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon Is there any way to modify your solution to take into consideration that some terms in the list may not have exponent and are pure fractions. I have limited knowledge of Mathematica, and I have been trying to understand how it works and using it on other expressions I have and have got error - The first two levels of {<list >} cannot be transposed. This is because some of the terms which I have after expanding are pure fraction and dont have exponent.

Comment: @BobHanlon With my limited knowledge of mathematica this is what I have understood in the line {coef1, exp1} = 
  Transpose[(List @@ (expr4 // Expand)) /. 
    a_*Exp[b_] :> {a, Simplify[b]}];
After expanding, list creates a vector of each term. Then using pattern matching with the form a_ and Exp[b_], it tries to separate coefficients and exponent into a and b which is then transposed. I frankly dont understand after that...... but the issue I am facing is if one or more terms after expand, doesnt have exponent, then obviously the transformation fails.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks alot. I am going through the link which you wrote above to understand your method.